# Finding separable decompositions of bipartite X-states using the methodology of Li and Qiao

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, ppt-criterion

Two recent papers of Jun-Li Li and Cong-Feng Qiao ([arXiv:1607.03364](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.03364) and [arXiv:1708.05336](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05336)) present "practical schemes for the decomposition of a bipartite mixed state into a sum of direct products of local density matrices".

I would like to know if this methodology can be applied to (two-qubit, qubit-qutrit, two-qutrit,...) $X$-states (only the diagonal and antidiagonal entries of the corresponding density matrices being non-zero).

If this can be successfully accomplished, it might be useful in addressing the question of what amount, if any, does the two-retrit $X$-state Hilbert-Schmidt PPT-probability of $\frac{16}{3 \pi^2} \approx 0.54038$ correspond to bound entangled states--an issue I have raised in my earlier postings ([Are X-state separability and PPT- probabilities the same for the two-qubit, qubit-qutrit, two-qutrit, etc. states?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5864/are-x-state-separability-and-ppt-probabilities-the-same-for-the-two-qubit-qubi) and [What proportions of certain sets of PPT-two-retrit states are bound entangled or separable?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5897/what-proportions-of-certain-sets-of-ppt-two-retrit-states-are-bound-entangled-or))